# Most efficient way to parse a known format string

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing

I have a string which is in the following format for example:

```
[ "{0}", "{1}", "{2}" ]
```

So I know there are always 3 parameters (of variable length) in that string format.

What is the most efficient way of parsing the string? (And maybe the shortest code along with it so I have to run some tests)

Thanks.

Comment: parsing...you mean looping and accessing sring elements ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want somebody else to do the job for you?

Comment: what output do u expect?

Comment: Not JSON. Expected output is the 2 string parameters between the quotes `{1}`, `{2}`, `{3}`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways, using `Regex` class or string methods.

Here is how it can be done using `Regex.Match`:

```
        string s = @"[ ""some test"", ""another test string"", ""hi there!"" ]";
        string[] vars = Regex.Matches(s, @"""([^""]*)""")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToArray();
```

Another way, using `Regex.Split`:

```
        vars = Regex.Split(s.Remove(s.Length - 3, 3).Remove(0, 3), @""",\s""");
```

Here is one way of doing it with string methods:

```
        vars = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("\"") + 1, s.LastIndexOf("\"") - 3)
                    .Split(new string[] {@""", """}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Is this an answer for the faster or easiest? (or both?)

Comment: It's a one possible way of doing it with a `Regex` class, it's up to OP to test the efficiency and speed compared to other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

1st solution: I think this is simplest 
 - Cut [ and ] (1st and last character)
 - Split by  "," -> trim() -> get 3 parts
 - Remove redundant characters (like "{ and }")
If you're sure that your expected strings don't contain " { } -> You can Remove them before split.

2nd solution: Use Regex

Answer (score 0):

Example: Extract --> How Are You?

```
string stuff = @"""{How}"", ""{Are}"", ""{You?}""";
string[] answer = (stuff.Replace(@"""{", String.Empty).Replace(@"}""", String.Empty)).Split(',');
```

Now the variable answer holds the three words!